# If I have a pppoe internet connection, with username and password required at log-in, how can it be used by a Win10 PC, a Linux PC and also as wi-fi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I mean I want so that phones and tablets too could also easily connect to said internet connection, so can I have wired AND wi-fi from the same internet connection? (at the same time?) I guess I need a router for that, OK but how to configure it and also if I often change my IP address by turning the internet on and off on let's say the Linux computer, will that affect other connections? Will I get a new dynamic IP that way? Plus how do I change my dynamic IP if I use a device with wi-fi connection? Do I have to restart the whole router for that?

Comment: You have asked a lot of questions here, some of which are tenuously related. You should limit a post to questions in a single element and post multiple questions addressing unrelated parts (eg sharing a pppoe account has nothing to do with changing dynamic IP's or restarting routers)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a pppoe Internet connection. I want so that phones and tablets
> too could also easily connect to said internet connection, so can I
> have wired AND wi-fi from the same internet connection? (at the same
> time?)
>
> I guess I need a router for that

Yes, you need a router that supports PPPoE  .

To connect it, open the WAN connection and select the PPPoe setup for user name and password.

I have done this and it works.

> I often change my IP address by turning the internet on and off on

That may depend in part on the ISP. You can restart the router from the router setup page. Try it. Some ISPs do not change IP address frequently.

> Plus how do I change my dynamic IP if I use a device with wi-fi
> connection? Do I have to restart the whole router for that?

This is really the same as the prior question. You can restart the router to get a new External IP address and see if that works. Restarting a router will not always reset the external IP address.

You can also log out of PPPoE and back in. That may change external IP or may not.

> I use a device with wi-fi connection

Get a Router that has both Ethernet connections and a Wireless setup. Set up wireless for your wireless devices.

Internal wireless (your devices) does not have anything to do with the IP assigned to the PPPoE connection.

A router is what you need to set up your system.

Comment: @Parts of this answer are goid, others (like advice to restart the router to reinitiate a PPPoE session/change IP) are off base.

Comment: The idea to restart a router to change the IP was posted as a suggestion as it may not work. But the question was asked and I posted the suggestion.. I did post some clarification.

Comment: Restarting a router is not a particularly good way of doing things - its like using a sledgehammer to crack a peanut.  Where possible it is much better to log into the router and restart the PPPoE session.  Most routers allow a way to do this, and it medans you don't break the LAN or put unneccessary stress on the router, while being faster.

Comment: Restarting PPPoE may or may not change IP; Restarting Router is simple (not any kind of sledgehammer) and may or may not change IP. I have done both.  However I did add logging out of PPPoE and back in again.